# building name value pairs using jquery each

Tags: jquery, each

I'm trying to create form-type name value pairs without using a HTML form by using dynamically generated data. I am looping through classes using JQuery EACH.

I have 2 fields that always come back as undefined or null. They happen to hold date values. One is the HTML value of a DIV and the other is an input field.

**JavaScript**

```
var cgiData="";
$(".fcmInput").each(function(){
    cgiData+="&sampleID="+ $(this).find(".fmcID").html();
    cgiData+="&procDate="+ $(this).find(".fcmPD").html();
    cgiData+="&anaDate="+ $(this).find(".fmcAD").val();
    cgiData+="&via="+ $(this).find(".fmcVIA").val();
    cgiData+="&viab="+ $(this).find(".fcmViability").val();
    cgiData+="&osid="+ $(this).find(".fcmOxidation").val();
    cgiData+="&mero="+ $(this).find(".fcmMerocyanine").val();
    cgiData+="&mito="+ $(this).find(".fcmMitopotential").val();
    cgiData+="&comp="+ $(this).find(".fcmCompDNA").val();
});
```

**HTML (there could be several *.fcmInput*)**:

```
<div id="x3HolderDiv" style="display: block;">
   <div id="fcmInput">
      <div class="fcmInput">
         <div class="fcmLbl">Sample ID:</div>
         <div class="ib fmcID bld2">123</div>
         <br>
         <div class="fcmLbl">Proc. Date:</div>
         <div class="ib fcmPD">12/01/2016</div>
         <br>
         <div class="fcmLbl">Analysis Date:</div>
         <input class="fcmAD jqdp hasDatepicker" value="1/10/2017" id="dp1484087188128"> 
         <div class="ib">Day:</div>
         <div class="ib fcmDays">40</div>
         <br>
         <div class="fcmLbl">VIA:</div>
         <input class="fcmVIA jqndo"><br>
         <div class="fcmLbl">Viability:</div>
         <input class="fcmViability jqndo"><br>
         <div class="fcmLbl">Oxidation:</div>
         <input class="fcmOxidation jqndo"><br>
         <div class="fcmLbl">Merocyanine:</div>
         <input class="fcmMerocyanine jqndo"><br>
         <div class="fcmLbl">Mitopotential:</div>
         <input class="fcmMitopotential jqndo"><br>
         <div class="fcmLbl">CompDNA :</div>
         <input class="fcmCompDNA jqndo"><br>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why are those 2 fields always null/undefined?

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qsdb10bh/1/)

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic for typographical error

Answer (score 1):

I had a type in my class name.

ARGGGG